# Identify Parent Child records using oracle SQL and avoid merge

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child

I have a requirement to find Parent Child Accounts using SQL query and avoid the merge process if the survivor is Child and Loser is Parent.
I have records in the **table x** in the following format

```
Survivor       Loser
400-GIZ-514   400-1729E3
```

**Table x** is a temporary table and the records in them are stored in base tables
In the **base table** the relationship between these 2 records is

```
          ROW_ID          PAR_OU_ID

Parent    400-1729E3      NULL
Child     400-GIZ-514     400-1729E3
```

Please help me with the query to identify these type of records and flag them so that they will be not be picked up the nightly process for merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be able to remove records from your temp table using

```
DELETE FROM tablex 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM  basetable
    WHERE basetable.row_id = tablex.survivor
          AND basetable.par_ou_id = tablex.loser
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will only retrieve records where the row has no matching parent:

```
SELECT * FROM BASE_TABLE A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BASE_TABLE B WHERE A.PAR_OU_ID = B.ROW_ID)
```